# Clojure take-while with logical and

Tags: clojure, predicates

I am learning Clojure and trying to solve Project's Euler (http://projecteuler.net/) problems using this language. 
Second problem asks to find the sum of the even-valued terms in Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million.

I've tried several approaches and would find next one most accurate if I could find where it's broken. Now it returns 0. I am pretty sure there is a problem with take-while condition but can't figure it out.

```
(reduce + 
  (take-while (and even? (partial < 4000000))  
    (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1]))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user> ((partial < 4000000) 1) 
false
```

Partial puts the static arguments first and the free ones at the end, so it's building the opposite of what you want. It is essentially producing `#(< 4000000 %)` instead of `#(< % 4000000)` as you intended, So just change the `>` to `<`:

```
user> (reduce +
        (take-while (and even? (partial > 4000000))
                         (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1]))))
9227464
```

or perhaps it would be more clear to use the anonymous function form directly:

```
user> (reduce +
              (take-while (and even? #(< % 4000000))
                          (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1]))))
9227464
```

Now that we have covered a bit about partial, let's break down a working solution. I'll use the thread-last macro `->>` to show each step separately.

```
user> (->> (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1]) ;; start with the fibs
           (map first)                              ;; keep only the answer   
           (take-while #(< % 4000000))              ;; stop when they get too big
           (filter even?)                           ;; take only the even? ones
           (reduce +))                              ;; sum it all together.
4613732
```

From this we can see that **we don't actually want to compose the predicates** `evan?` and less-than-4000000 on a `take-while` because this would stop as soon as either condition was true leaving only the number zero. Rather we want to use one of the predicates as a limit and the other as a filter.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for explanation!
Now I've got another problem - for some reason the result (9227464) is twice as many as real solution (4613732). How has it doubled?

Comment: That's because `(and even? (partial > 4000000))` returns `(partial > 4000000)` -- it's *not* composing the two predicates in any sense, but rather computing the logical "and" of `even?` and `(partial > 4000000)`. These are neither `false` nor `nil`, so they're both truthy, so the last one of them will be returned. Ultimately only `(partial > 4000000)` ends up being used by `take-while`.

Answer (score 10):

To compose multiple predicates in this way, you can use `every-pred`:

```
(every-pred even? (partial > 4000000))
```

The return value of this expression is a function that takes an argument and returns `true` if it is both even and greater than 4000000, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Why do I get 0 for this code then?
    (take-while (every-pred even? (partial > 100)) (range))

Comment: You get a sequence `'(0)`, because `take-while` stops consuming as soon as the predicate returns a non true value. It will return true for 0 (being even and smaller than 100), but false for 1 because it's not even. So you may want to use `filter` instead.

Comment: I think you mean (partial < 4000000), based on your verbal description of the function.

Comment: user> (map (partial < 4000000) [0 Integer/MAX_VALUE]) => (false true)